# Guard Against Invalid Parameter Input

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a parameter being passed through to a procedure that takes in a list of ints in the form of a varchar as follows:

```
@sSortFilter    VARCHAR(512) = ''
```

I want to validate it on the procedure side so if someone puts a comma at the beginning before the int when executing the procedure such as:

```
, 23, 24
```

Instead of `23, 24` it will guard against that so the procedure does not blow up.

Is there a way to guard against this using SQL?

Comment: what would be the DESIRED output of the SPROC if it was sent bad formed data?  Look at try/catch...

Comment: Write some logic at the start of your proc that if the parameter starts with a character that will blow up your proc, you change it to something that won't.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Example:

```
 BEGIN TRY

  SELECT 1/0;
  --This is where you would break your list down, if it fails here the catch will fire
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 -- how you want to handle the error.
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Case statement` with some `string functions` to check whether your input has leading `comma` and override it. Try this.

```
DECLARE @sSortFilter VARCHAR(512) = ', 23, 24'

SELECT @sSortFilter = CASE
                        WHEN LEFT(Ltrim(@sSortFilter), 1) = ',' THEN Ltrim(Substring(@sSortFilter, 2, Len(@sSortFilter)))
                        ELSE @sSortFilter
                      END

SELECT @sSortFilter
```